# Get dynamic content from database to controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in database where I kept keywords/title/description. Now I want to get the data (content) in controller function ::::

how can I get data from database into a function of controller ::::

```
public function index()
{
   $data=array();

   $data['title']=" Title "; // need the title dynamic
   $data['keywords']="Keywords"; // need the keyword dynamic
   $data['keywords']="Description"; // need the description dynamic

}
```

Comment: create queries in model and call that function in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

in controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data=array();
    $data['content']=$this->model_name->getContent();   

}
```

in model

```
function getContent()
{
    $data=array();
    return $data=$this->db->select('title,keywords,description')->get('table_name')->result_array();
}
```

This is the general way to fetch data from database. Please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: thank you so much .... now how can I show them in my view file ??? like::: <?php echo $content['title']; ?>   ????? please

Comment: yes use <?php echo $content['title']; ?> to show.please accept the answer if it's helped you.thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      $data['title'] = $row->title;
      $data['Keywords'] = $row->Keywords;
      $data['Description']= $row->Description;
   }
}
```

you can use the following variables in your view file

```
$title, $Keywords, $Description.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. how I can I show them in view page in head tag ?? please

Answer (score 0):

Create a model function that will query the database to return your controller the results. You need to learn about `CI` first. [Learn Codeignter first!](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)